# Как получить url ссылку на картинку вк

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот, модули

Изучаю python, работаю с api вк, использую модуль vkbottle bot (то есть для группы).
Суть в том, что человек пишет в группу сообщение, к примеру,  "привет" (и к сообщению прикрепляет картинку)..
Мне нужно извлечь url (оригинал) картинки - как это сделать?, код прикрепляю

```
from vkbottle import Bot, Message, PhotoUploader
from vkbottle import Bot, Message, VKError


bot = Bot('ЗДЕСЬ ТОКЕН', debug=True)

@bot.on.message(text='привет', lower=True) #тут он присылает текст с прикрепленной картинкой
async def wrapper(ans: Message):
#здесь нужно как-то извлечь url(оригинал)
    await ans(f"Готово!") 

bot.run_polling()
```

Comment: зачем вам конкретно ссылка? вам же нужно изображение

Comment: https://github.com/timoniq/vkbottle/blob/master/docs/api.ru.md#uploader-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD